# Junk decryption-- a puzzle I found on a wargame site

Tags: cipher, computer-puzzle

I have found this puzzle and I wanted to share it with you to see if anyone can solve it, because I can't figure it out.

> **Can you put this all together?**
>   From: Agent J
>   To: adib
>
> Agent,
>
> See if you can piece all these intercepted pieces of intel together, our team is really struggling to do so. We've got an encrypted string, and this weird calendar image with a date circled.
>
> Anyway, here's the encrypted string: `NXIS24CuEq@uEq@uEq@u`
>
> See if you can figure it out.
>
> J

The calendar image:

[image]

Comment: yeah the program will only run on Linux machine.

Comment: Actually what i understand, is when they put the encrypted text into that program it gives an encrypted text also, from the hint also i think there should be a way to write the date and implement it in the program since it only accepts one argument.

Comment: Also if you put any text into the program, it gives you junk text, and when you import that junk text again into the program it gives you the orginal text you putted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not self-contained and requires installing software.

Comment: This is off-topic for multiple reasons.  its origin is a challenge in the CyberStart program, which even if not strictly speaking an ongoing competition is close enough to one for our purposes to nix it; there is insufficient information to decrypt the string in the puzzle posting as it now stands; and as originally posed, It is not self-contained and requires installing a binary program. Since the program in question relies on the date as part of its crypto algorithm, it is impossible to decrypt without the program, and the program is SANS / CyberStart intellectual property.

Answer (score 0):

You set the time on your computer to the date given on the calendar and run the file.

I suspect the file was using some type of time/date based encryption.

Hello fellow Cyberstart competitors!

Comment: Could you please explain further? A timezone isn't something you can set to a date, and I don't see a file referenced in the question. Otherwise, welcome to Puzzling! Why don't you take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour)?

Comment: Sorry, the file to be run was given with the challenge, I know this because I'm doing the same challenge as he is right now.